# Avoid multiple calls to API using spring webclient with flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, spring-webclient

Both those calls are client http api:

```java
Flux<SavingsViewFilter> views = savingsApi.getViewFilterSavings(viewId);
            Flux<Group> groups = groupsApi.getAllGroups();
```

and return a Flux

```java
requestBodySpec.retrieve().bodyToFlux(returnType);
```

I need to filter element inside the `Flux<Group>`, based on values from eacg `view.getGroupId()`

```java
        return views.flatMap(view ->
                groups
                        .filter(group -> Objects.equals(group.getGroupId(), view.getGroupId()))
                        .flatMap(group -> Flux.just(DepositAccount.builder()
                                .agencyName(group.getGroupName())
                                .settlementAccount(view.getName())
                                .build())));
```

It is working, but the problem is that it's doing for each view object, one more HTTP request to getAllGroups.

How can I avoid multiple requests to getAllGroups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are subscribing to groups for every element of views.

You can use join to only subscribe to each once, and then join element by element.

```java
views
    //Join fluxes and create tuple for each pair
    .join(groups, s-> Flux.never(),s-> Flux.never(),Tuples::of)
    //Filter out any that don't have matching groupIds
    .filter(t -> t.getT1().getGroupId().equals(t.getT2().getGroupId()))
    //Use map, not flatMap since builder is not blocking
    .map(t -> DepositAccount.builder()
        .agencyName(t.getT2().getGroupName())
        .settlementAccount(t.getT1().getName())
        .build()
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Really this is not the correct question and needs to be thought through a little better.

The end result is that you are trying to match the `ids` for `views` with the `ids` for `groups` and create a join object. This is not the purpose that the `Flux` API is meant for. In the end it looks like you are trying to do that task with two loops which is a very inefficient way to do that.

It is much better if you investigate alternative approaches.

1) If both `group` and `view` and database tables then use SQL to join. Create a new endpoint that is efficient.

2) Put one collection into a map and use it to combine the two entities.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
class View {
    Integer id;
    String view;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
class Group {
    Integer id;
    String group;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Combined {
    String view;
    String group;
}

private void run() {
    Flux<View> views = Flux.just(new View(1, "v1"), new View(2, "v2"), new View(3, "v3"));
    Flux<Group> groups = Flux.just(new Group(2, "g2"), new Group(3, "g3"), new Group(4, "g4"));

    views.collectMap(View::getId)
            .flatMapMany(viewMap -> groups.filter(group -> viewMap.containsKey(group.getId()))
                    .map(group ->
                            new Combined(viewMap.get(group.getId()).getView(), group.getGroup()))
            )
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}
```